# New activity sometimes doesn't start

Tags: android, android-activity, android-pendingintent

In certain circumstances I need to call `exit()` in my application (I know it's not the best way to finish but this is not the question). Also I want to show a new dialog which informs the user about the crash.

I created a new activity class, a new broadcast receiver, registered them in manifest. Next, I call:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, AppCloseReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);
try
{
    pendingIntent.send();
}
catch(Exception ex){}

System.exit(0);
```

The problem is that new window appears **sometimes**! First I thought that `System.exit(0);` fires before new activity have a chance to start (because of async call, thought couldn't find this in documentation) so I added `Thread.sleep(1000)` between `pendingIntent.send();` and `System.exit(0);`, but the result is the same - new window appears **sometimes**. There's nothing in the logs, no exception.

The new activity is just a static text.

Comment: This is absolutely not reliable. Calling `System.exit()` basically shuts down the VM. You can't guarantee that anything will happen when you shut down the VM. You certainly cannot expect anything to be shown in the UI. Please explain your use case and maybe we can suggest an alternative.

Comment: My use case is to `exit` under certain conditions and tell the user why the application stopped. As alternative I'm using a notification but I want more persistence solution that should stay on the screen and wait until user closes it manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't reliable. If you cause the VM to shutdown you cannot display anything, as there is no longer a VM running. The only reliable way to do this would be to ensure the `BroadcastReceiver` and `Activity` run in a different OS process to display your message. This also isn't 100% reliable, because depending on the nature of the exception, your existing VM may not be able to start the other components, but it is probably more reliable than your current implementation. For example, if your app crashes due to `OutOfMemoryException`, it probably isn't possible to do anything useful.

To ensure that a component runs in a separate process, add

```
android:process=":other"
```

to the `<activity>` and `<receiver>` definitions in the manifest for those components.

You should also try to delay the call to `System.exit()` to give the VM a chance to actually initiate the launch of the dialog. Also, you don't need to use a `PendingIntent` for this. Try something like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, AppCloseReceiver.class);
sendBrodcast(intent);
// Start separate Thread to terminate the process
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @override
    public void run() {
        SystemClock.sleep(1000); // Sleep a bit to give the VM enough time to actually send the broadcast Intent
        System.exit(0);
    }
}).start();
```